# Unable to send Enter-Stroke to screen session from script

Tags: shell, sh, gnu-screen, enter

I would like to control a screen session (A) from  another screen session (B). Therefore I wrote a little script that I will run in session B:

```
#!/bin/sh

clear

while :
do
screen -S SessionA -X stuff '^C'
screen -S SessionA -X stuff 'java -jar jarFile.jar'
screen -S SessionA -X stuff `echo -ne '\015'`

sleep 30
done
```

So it basically ends the current process of session A and restarts it by sending the java command and an Enter-stroke.

Sending the enter-stroke by using `echo -ne '\015'` worked flawlessly in the terminal. However, it does not work from the script.

Does anyone know either:
How to send a command to a screen session from a script or simply
How to send an Enter-stroke to a screen session from a script?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just found the answer myself. 
In case someone stumbles on the same problem: Instead of using `echo -ne '\015'` simply put a `^M` at the end of the command.

New script:

```
#!/bin/sh

clear

while :
do
screen -S SessionA -X stuff '^C'
screen -S SessionA -X stuff 'java -jar jarFile.jar^M'

sleep 30
done
```